# Error updating Node - ubuntu (WSL) - how to update node

Tags: node.js, version-control, nodes

I need at least any >14 version of node, but when i tried to update i had to uninstall. now i1m trying to install the 16 version but i keep gettimg this error:

> Unpacking nodejs (16.19.0-deb-1nodesource1) ... dpkg: error processing
> archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.19.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi',
> which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3 dpkg-deb:
> error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were
> encountered while processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.19.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb E:
> Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

To install NodeJS Firstly make sure to update your packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then make sure to have `curl` installed, `sudo apt install curl -y`

Then import NodeJS repo by `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_NODEJS_VERSION | sudo -E bash -`
Make sure to change `NODEJS_VERSION` to the version u wish to install, for example if u want to instal v16 change it to `16.x` then simply run `sudo apt install nodejs -y` to install nodejs

Hope that helped!